# optparse csv.reader

Tags: python, csv, path, optparse

Can somebody help me, I'm trying to link an optparse with a csv reader, but I have been unable to do so. Below is my code:

```
import csv
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('--i1', action='store', type='string', dest='input1file', help='[REQUIRED] The input .csv file path.')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
input1file = options.input1file

data = csv.reader(open('input1file','r'))
temp = open('C:\Practice\output_edited.csv','a')
for column in data:
    temp.write(column[0]+','+column[len(column)-1]+'\n')
    print column[0]+','+column[len(column)-1]+'\n'
temp.close()
```

I don't know how to connect the add_option part so that the user can type in the filename path.
Thanks!

I updated my code. Still can't get it working though.

**Update1:**

```
import sys
import csv
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('--i1', action='store', type='string', dest='input1file', help='[REQUIRED] The input .csv file path.')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
input1file = options.input1file

try:
    input1file = args[1]
except IndexError:
    sys.exit("Input file required, none given")

data = csv.reader(open(sys.args[1],'r'))
temp = open('C:\Practice\output_edited.csv','a')
for column in data:
    temp.write(column[0]+','+column[len(column)-1]+'\n')
    print column[0]+','+column[len(column)-1]+'\n'
temp.close()
```

Comment: Don't quote `'input1file'` unless that's the actual filename you want.

Comment: consider switching to argparse.  It's what all the cool kids are doing these days.

Comment: Also `optparse` is deprecated.

Comment: Get rid of the try/except statement, and use `data = csv.reader(open(input1file, 'r'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify `--i1` on the command line, `options.input1file` is `None`, since you don't provide a default value.

```
myscript.py --i1 input.txt
```

Since `--i1` is required, it really shouldn't be an option (since it is not optional). Take the input file from `args`, instead:

```
parser = OptionParser()
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
try:
    input1file = args[0]
except IndexError:
    sys.exit("Input file required, none given")
```

Or, as mgilson suggested, use `argparse` instead. It supports named positional parameters.

Comment: @user1546610 Instead of saying `'[REQUIRED]'` in the help text, you could pass `required=True` to actually enforce that it is passed.

Comment: @Dougal -- Nope, that only works with `argparse`.  `optparse` took the stance that "required option" is contradictory in english and therefore required options should actually be arguments.

Comment: I am stick with version 2.6 so I can't use argparse.

Comment: @mgilson Ah, good point. I haven't actually used `optparse` in a long time and forgot about that silliness.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = csv.reader(open('input1file','r'))
```

should be

```
data = csv.reader(open(input1file,'r'))
```

Based on your comment, it looks like you're forgetting to use the `--i1` argument.  If it is actually required, you should enforce that:

e.g.:

```
if not input1file:
  print "What?  you were supposed to give '--i1 filename', but you didn't.  Shame on you!"
  sys.exit(1)
```

*note that this is easier to do in `argparse`.  You just pass `required=True` to the `add_argument` method*

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've tried that. It gave: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, None type found

Comment: @user1546610 -- how are you calling the program?

Comment: @user1546610 -- Yes, but are you calling it as `myprogram -i1 myfile` or just as `myprogram`?